# Calling an arbitrary class method for many objects

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, refactoring

I want to create a generic function to call specific class methods for every object within a list. For example, say we have objects a, b, and c that all have methods eat(), sleep(), and code().

My goal is to create

```
def do_all(fn, objs):
    for obj in objs:
        obj.fn()
```

Such that I can call do_all(eat, [a,b,c]) or do_all(sleep, [a,b,c]). Note that each object is not necessarily from the same class -- they each inherit and override certain methods, and thus eat/sleep/code all perform different actions.

Currently I have many functions for each method within the class.
e.g.

```
def eat_all(objs):
    for obj in objs:
        obj.eat()
```

However, I feel like there must be a better way. Any help would be great!

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with your approach. You could pass a string, though, and use `getattr`, so, suppose for `def do_all(method_name, objs)`, and you pass `do_all('eat', [a, b, c])`, you can simply define it as `for obj in objs: getattr(method_name, obj)()`

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Worked beautifully. I used the parent class to get the function names, via `<parent>.<method>.__name__` so refactoring hopefully won't be an issue. Thank you so much! 

FYI: You have the arguments mixed up, `getattr(obj, method_name)()`.